# optaplanner prefers worse solution than possible

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm running into a weird case where the final solution is not the best one achievable, let me explain:

i have two planning entities, PlannerTask and PlannerTaskResourceAllocation. PlannerTasks's planning variable is a start index (which is converted to and from a date in a calendar) and PlannerTaskResourceAllocation's planning variable is a TaskResource. I set up the rules so that for every start index change and for every resource change i deduct a certain amount of soft score, **where the penalty for changing indexes is larger than for changing resource**:

```
//this rule deducts 10 soft score for every resource allocation change
rule "taskResourceChangeRule"
    when
        PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(!resource.equals(originalResource))
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

//this rule deducts a 1000 soft score times the different in index when chnaging a task index
rule "taskDateChangeRule"
    when
        PlannerTask($startIndex : startIndex, $originalStartIndex : originalStartIndex, $startIndex != $originalStartIndex )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, Math.abs($originalStartIndex - $startIndex) * -1000);
end
```

I set up a test case where there are sufficient resources for optaplanner to allocate them to the tasks without needing to move them but when i run it ends up moving the tasks anyway and not allocating the resources. Now i know that it's a bit more complicated than that and you need more info to understand why this might happening, but to prove that this is indeed weird, i simply removed the PlannerTask entity from the configuration and this resulted in the expected behaviour with a better score!

So:

- With the PlannerTask entity and corresponding move included in the configuration, i get the unexpected result of tasks being moved and the undesirable score of: 0hard/-28000soft
- With the PlannerTask entity removed from the configuration i get the expected behaviour of task indexes remaining the same and and the correct resources being allocated and the better score of: 0hard/-2000soft (almost 15 times better)

So to simplify, it is obviously possible for optaplanner to reach the preferable solution also when the PlannerTask entity is included, then why is it not reaching it then?

To make things even easier i added a

```
<fixedProbabilityWeight>100.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
```

on the resource allocation change move so it will generate more of those, that didn't help.

The only thing that i think might be the cause for this is the filter i have on the Resource Allocation move, that checks that the resources assigned are of the correct type and class required by the resource allocation entity, and turning on Trace logging shows how many moves it is rejecting: (this is just a snippet, there are maybe 10000 of similar lines in the console)

```
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.d.a.tabu.ValueTabuAcceptor     :         Proposed move (replacing resource tractor2 for task with id 100 with tractor2) is tabu and is therefore not accepted.
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46980), score (0hard/-28002soft), accepted (false), move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 100 with tractor2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46981) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 98 with dave daveson Working as ATV Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46982) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor2 for task with id 102 with tractor2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46983) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 98 with oil1).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46984) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 101 with oil2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46985) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 97 with dave daveson Working as ATV Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46986) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 97 with fertilizer1).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46987) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 101 with joe joeson Working as ATV Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46988) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 99 with oil2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46989) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 100 with joe joeson Working as ATV Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46990) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 100 with oil2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46991) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 104 with joe joeson Working as ATV Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46992) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 103 with dave daveson Working as Spreader Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46993) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 99 with oil2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46994) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 101 with joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46995) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource tractor1 for task with id 104 with fungicide2).
2016-03-16 09:57:12.187 TRACE   --- [           main] o.o.c.i.l.decider.LocalSearchDecider     :         Move index (46996) not doable, ignoring move (replacing resource joe joeson Working as Tractor Driver for task with id 101 with joe joeson Working as ATV Driver).
```

Any ideas?

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
<environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>

<!-- Domain model configuration -->
<solutionClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.ActivitySolution</solutionClass>
<entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTask</entityClass>
<entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTaskResourceAllocation</entityClass>

<!-- Score configuration -->
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <scoreDrl>com/rdthree/plenty/services/activities/planner/activity-scoring.drl</scoreDrl>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
<termination>
    <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
    <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0soft</bestScoreLimit>
    <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
</termination>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="resourceAllocationSelector">
            <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTaskResourceAllocation</entityClass>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="resourceAllocationSelector" />
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>resource</variableName>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="taskSelector">
            <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTask</entityClass>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
            <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</sorterManner>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="taskSelector" />
            <filterClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.filters.TaskLengthChnageFilter</filterClass>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>startIndex</variableName>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>

<localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
        <moveListFactory>
            <fixedProbabilityWeight>100.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
            <moveListFactoryClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.MoveResourceAllocationMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
            <filterClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.planner.filters.TaskLengthChnageFilter</filterClass>
            <entitySelector id="taskMoveSelector">
                <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.services.activities.helpers.dtos.PlannerTask</entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>startIndex</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>

    <acceptor>
        <valueTabuSize>7</valueTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>2000</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
</localSearch>
```

Drools file:

```
//this rule deducts a 1000 soft score times the different in index when chnaging a task index
rule "taskDateChangeRule"
    when
        PlannerTask($startIndex : startIndex, $originalStartIndex : originalStartIndex, $startIndex != $originalStartIndex )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, Math.abs($originalStartIndex - $startIndex) * -1000);
end

//this rule deducts 1000 soft score for every time unit of space between consecutive tasks of the same activity
rule "taskNonConsecutivPlacement"
    when
        PlannerTask($task1Activity : activity, $task1Id : id, $task1endIndex : endIndex, $task1IndexInActivity : indexInActivity)
        PlannerTask(activity == $task1Activity, $task1Id != id, indexInActivity == $task1IndexInActivity+1, $task2startIndex : startIndex)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, Math.abs($task2startIndex - $task1endIndex) * -1000);
end

//this rule deducts 10 soft score for every resource allocation change
rule "taskResourceChangeRule"
    when
        PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(!resource.equals(originalResource))
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

// This rule creates a constraint based on overlap of two tasks which use the 
// same labourer at the same time. The constraint is multipled by the size of the overlap in days
rule "TaskLabourerTimeOverlap"
    when
        $task1 : PlannerTask()
        $task1ResourceAllocation : PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(taskId == $task1.id, resource instanceof SkillsAndRates, $task1UserId : resource.getUser().getId())

        $task2 : PlannerTask($task1.id != id)
        eval($task1.overlaps($task2))
        $task2ResourceAllocation : PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(taskId == $task2.id, resource instanceof SkillsAndRates, resource.getUser().getId().equals($task1UserId))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, (int)$task1.getOverlapLegth($task2) * -1);
        $task1ResourceAllocation.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task2ResourceAllocation.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task1.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task2.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
end

// This rule creates a constraint based on overlap of a task and it's labour days off
// The constraint is multipled by the size of the overlap in days
rule "TaskLabourerDayOffOverlap"
    when
        $task1 : PlannerTask()
        $task1ResourceAllocation : PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(taskId == $task1.id, resource instanceof SkillsAndRates, $task1UserId : resource.getUser().getId())
        $labourDayOff : PlannerLabourDayOff(user.getId() == $task1UserId, $task1.contains(dateIndex))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
        $task1ResourceAllocation.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task1.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
end

// This rule creates a constraint based on overlap of two tasks which use the 
// same equipment at the same time. The constraint is multipled by the size of the overlap in days
rule "TaskEquipmentTimeOverlap"
    when
        $task1 : PlannerTask()
        $task1ResourceAllocation : PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(taskId == $task1.id, resource instanceof EquipmentEquipmentTypes, $task1EquipmentId : resource.getEquipment().getId())

        $task2 : PlannerTask($task1.id != id)
        eval($task1.overlaps($task2))
        $task2ResourceAllocation : PlannerTaskResourceAllocation(taskId == $task2.id, resource instanceof EquipmentEquipmentTypes, resource.getEquipment().getId() == $task1EquipmentId)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, (int)$task1.getOverlapLegth($task2) * -1);
        $task1ResourceAllocation.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task2ResourceAllocation.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task1.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task2.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
end

// This rule create a constraint based on product defficiency for a product at a taks's start date
rule "TaskProductShortage"
    when
        $task : PlannerTask( $taskId : id, $taskNeedsProductBy : startIndex)
        $allocation : PlannerTaskResourceAllocation( taskId == $taskId, resource != null, resource instanceof Product)
        OnHandForProduct(dateIndex == $taskNeedsProductBy, productId == $allocation.resource.getId(), $onHandAmount : amount, amount - $allocation.amount  <= 0)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $allocation.getAmount() * -1);
        $allocation.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
        $task.setState(ScheduleState.CONFLICT.toString());
end
```

Comment: I didn't fully read your question and I don't actually know optaplanner but is the solution it calculates valid? And how do you determine there's a better solution? If you do that manually or just know there is it might be the settings for the heuristics algorithms. Anyways heuristics are not meant to return the optimal solution in every case but a good enough solution. That's why they're preferred over exact algorithms for more complex problems: finding the best solution might take too much space and time so the heuristics try to get as good as possible with limited resources.

Comment: the answers for your questions are in the question you didn't fully read :)

Comment: Read the follow sections in the docs: **score traps** and also **pillar moves** and **custom moves**. But first turn on **environmentMode** FULL_ASSERT or FAST_ASSERT to exclude score corruption as a cause.

Comment: Hey Geoffrey, Thanks for your input, i tried what you said but i'm still having the same exact issue. Do you have any more ideas as to what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: You tried score traps, pillar moves and custom moves?

Comment: I am already using custom moves, Pillar moves are not applicable for this purpose, i read the part about score traps and it seems that my scoring method considers the issues suggested there: "A trapped score constraint uses the same weight for different constraint matches, when it could just as easily use a different weight", this is exactly not what i am doing, this is evident in the first code snippet in the question